# Does a RHEL7 docker container need subscription?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rhel7, docker-container, docker-image

I have a rhel7 host with docker in it.
I have build a image with also rhel7 as base image.
But when I run the container & do `yum update` or try to install in package with yum, it gives me below error.

```
"This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription.you can use subscription manager to register"
```

I have already subscribed the host RHEL Machine. Do I need to subscribe each and every container with rhel image?

Or

Do I need to subscribe in the dockerfile itself while building the image?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Docker hub, you can find some Red Hat docker images , like

https://hub.docker.com/r/richxsl/rhel6.5/

or

https://hub.docker.com/r/lionelman45/rhel7/

but in order to update them, you will need a valid subscription

You will find Red Hat docker images on the Red Hat site, at

https://access.redhat.com/containers

this article summarizes what you need in order to build a Red hat docker image

http://cloudgeekz.com/625/howto-create-a-docker-image-for-rhel.html

it begins with

`Pre-requisites
Access to RHEL package repository.`

Comment: The cloudgeekz.com link does not work anymore

Comment: Here's the archived page: https://web.archive.org/web/20200925170954/http://cloudgeekz.com/625/howto-create-a-docker-image-for-rhel.html

Answer (score 3):

With [RHEL 8 Red Hat now offers a universal base image](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introducing-red-hat-universal-base-image) for docker containers which does not require a subscription.

Comment: Can you use regular Docker with this or do you have to use 'podman'

Comment: Yes, you you can use the images with regular docker.

Comment: If I don't use a subscription, I cannot find packages normally found in CodeReady repo.

Answer (score 1):

The RHEL UBI image contains 3 default repos (see `yum repolist`).  Subscription is required for the CodeReady repo (`ubi-8-codeready-builder`).

If you decide to NOT subscribe then you can hide those warnings with:

```
yum --disableplugin=subscription-manager install <package>
```

Source:
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/03/24/red-hat-universal-base-images-for-docker-users/

Answer (score 0):

The [RHEL 7 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html-single/getting_started_with_containers/index) covers this. Please use your subscription to read section 1.4.

Paraphrasing what the documentation says:

- You must use a subscribed RHEL 7 host to build containers
- Containers based on RHEL 7 will use the host's subscription automatically and be able to access the RHEL 7 yum repositories

If you are trying to build RHEL 7 based containers on a properly subscribed RHEL 7 host and it doesn't work, you might be running into a bug. I would contact support to try and sort this out.

Comment: I found that registration was required when trying to build a rhel based container using 'docker build', but not necessary when using 'podman build'. 
If using docker build, the registration can be done in Docker file by adding extra  RUN steps `RUN subscription-manager register --username=<rhn-user> --password=<rhnpwd> --auto-attach`. And unregister at end of build: `RUN subscription-manager unregister`

Answer (score 0):

I used podman to pull RHEL 7 Universal Base Image, like this:

```
podman pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi
```

After that, although I still saw the warning message:

```
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
```

but there was no issue to use yum for package installation or update.

You can also use RHEL8 ubi in the same approach without any issue.

Comment: You can hide the warning with: yum --disableplugin=subscription-manager

Answer (score 0):

I found this article that clarifies the RHEL UBI images which do not need a subscription.
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/03/24/red-hat-universal-base-images-for-docker-users/

```
docker search registry.access.redhat.com/ubi
docker run -it --name test registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:8.1 bash
```

I tried yum to install a netcat command which worked seamlessly